# What is the purpose of float:left on an unordered list when creating a horizontal navigation bar?

Tags: css, css-float

The code sample below works almost the same, if I include or remove the 'float: left' line. The only difference is the float left version moves the blocks below it up a bit more, but not more than a line break. I don't understand why you would add floating to an element set to 100% width. To my understanding,this prevents everything below it from flowing around it. Isn't that the purpose of floating?

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

li
{
    display: inline;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this works is because your `<li>` display is set to `inline`.  This means that all elements with of this HTML tag will show up on the same line as all other ones.  In other words, there will be no line-break.  I would suggest the following instead:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden; /* This will ensure there's a line break after using float for the list items */
}

li {
    float: left;
}
```

This way you can ensure that each list item can also use `margin` and `padding` properly as opposed to inline elements which act as characters in a string of text normally would.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been wondering the advantage of floating over inline. The ability to use margins and padding really clarifies that for me.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to hear it worked for you.  If you liked my answer then mark it as correct so other people who come to this post can see it as correct!

Answer (score 1):

The float property is meant to allow an object to be displayed inline with the text directing it to one side. Float left is thus a lot like inline but with the exception that the element being floated is aligned towards the left or the right. It is not necessary to use the float:left; flag for what you are trying to do, It can often be better to place the ul where you want it using position, margin, padding, left , top , right , bottom instead. This usualy gives a more controllable result.

Here is an example fiddle of what happens when switching between no float and float left.
http://jsfiddle.net/um9LV/

Answer (score 0):

The [**float**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float) CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

when an element is floated it is taken out of the normal flow of the document.  It is shifted to the left or right until it touches the edge of it's containing box or another floated element.

Answer (score 0):

`float:left` - use float to get block elements to slide next to each other

`display:block` - Displaying the links as block elements makes the whole link area clickable (not just the text), and it allows us to specify the width