# Dropdown menu not aligning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a problem where my list for my dropdown menu appears in another location then expected to be at.

[image]

This is part of my code. I've tried multiple references, like YouTube, w3school, and etc.

(HTML / JS)

```css
.dropdownButton {
  color: #fe4b4b;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 165%;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}

.dropdown {
  align-items: center;
}

.list {
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: 0.3s;
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #3a4172;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  list-style: none;
}

.newlist {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.links {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 130%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.links:hover {
  color: #fefb4b;
  border-left: 5px solid #fefb4b;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.025);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li id="regular"><a href="#">EARN</a></li>
    <li id="regular"><a href="#">PROMOCODES</a></li>
    <li id="regular"><a href="#">WITHDRAW</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdownButton" href="#">MORE ▼</button>
      <ul class="list">
        <a href="#"><button class="links">REFFERALS</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button class="links">DAILY</button></a>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="login"><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li>
  </ul>

  <script>
    //Dropdown
    let click = document.querySelector('.dropdownButton');
    let list = document.querySelector('.list');

    click.addEventListener("click", () => {
      list.classList.toggle('newlist');
    });
    //Dropdown End
  </script>
</header>
```

I don't know how to fix it cause I'm a beginner, any help on fixing it / guidance would be nice! Thanks.

Comment: Just an observation: you are giving multiple elements the same `id` attribute, that could cause lots of issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're going to need more CSS and possibly HTML to see exactly why your code is behaving unexpectedly.

Definitely mimicking the first comment on here though: IDs should be unique to each element. If you want those **li** elements to have the same styling, use a class:

```
<li class="regular">
```

This will apply the same styling to different elements.

However, when an element appears in the top left like that, in my experience, I am using the CSS 'display', 'float', or 'position' properties incorrectly. If you haven't already, look into how the float and display properties function (as well as relative vs absolute positioning).

Check out [this codepen.io](https://codepen.io/bmills20/pen/PoBRwJd), where I have it working by adding:

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

This allows your list items to exist on the same line properly. My guess is that you are using

```
li {
    display: inline; /* incorrect usage */
}
```

to get them on the same horizontal axis. This is fine for regular text elements, but will cause "unexpected" behavior with positioning of child elements. For a more detailed explanation, please see this StackOverflow post:

[What is the purpose of float:left on an unordered list when creating a horizontal navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999686/what-is-the-purpose-of-floatleft-on-an-unordered-list-when-creating-a-horizonta).

*Tip for next time: if your local looks very different than what you get if you paste into codepen.io, people will be less inclined to help you.*

*If this properly answered your question please upvote and mark best answer :)*